# what does "..." mean inside of bash?

Tags: command-line

I am learning how to use the bash shell, and one example for the cp command was `cp file... directory`. It noted that:

> A note on notation: ... signifies that an item can be repeated one or
>   more times.

that is all it said. I can't quite understand what that means. can someone please give me a bit more of an in depth explanation? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think `...` means anything in terms of the shell, in this context. It's probably just the author's way of indicating that you may copy multiple files for example by typing

```
cp file1 file2 file3 directory
```

In fact, the `cp` command's manual page uses a similar notation:

> ```
> NAME
>        cp - copy files and directories
>
> SYNOPSIS
>        cp [OPTION]... [-T] SOURCE DEST
>        cp [OPTION]... SOURCE... DIRECTORY
>        cp [OPTION]... -t DIRECTORY SOURCE...
>
> DESCRIPTION
>        Copy SOURCE to DEST, or multiple SOURCE(s) to DIRECTORY.
> ```

You may see a sequence of *two* dots in other contexts - for example in brace expansion `{1..5}`